# Total Download and Upload Cannot Reach More Than 4GB on Delphi 7 with Tmagras component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This is my function for converting a byte count to a string. It cannot reach 4GB:

```
function BytesToFriendlyString(Value : Int64) : string;
const
  OneKB = 1024;
  OneMB = OneKB * 1024;
  OneGB = OneMB * 1024;
begin
  if Value < OneKB then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 B',Value)
  else if Value < OneMB then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 KB', Value / OneKB)
  else if Value < OneGB then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 MB', Value / OneMB)
  else if Value > OneGB then
    Result := FormatFloat('#,##0.00 GB', Value / OneGB)
end; (*BytesToFriendlyString*)
```

And this is how it is being used:

```
K := PerfNrList [I] ;  
if (K > MgRasPer.TotPorts) or (K < 0) then K := 0 ;
with ConSpeedList.Items [I] do begin
  Subitems [1] := BytesToFriendlyString(MgRasPer.PerfXmitCur [K]) ;
  Subitems [2] := BytesToFriendlyString(MgRasPer.PerfRecvCur [K]) ;
```

How can I make it handle more than 4GB?

Comment: The problem is not your function. The library stores the counts in a 32 bit integer, right? That's what needs to be changed.

Comment: how should i do? im noob sir

Comment: I don't know. If I'm right then the library would need source modifications. If that's not possible, look for a different library.

Comment: What are you trying to use this component for

Comment: The function handles values > 4GB just fine (but it has a logic bug that prevents it from handling values *exactly* 1GB). It is obvious that the caller does not support values > 4GB before calling the function. In your example, that means `PerfXmitCur[K]` and `PerfRecvCur[K]` are likely returning `Integer` or `Cardinal` instead of `Int64`.

Comment: you alright sir... but wht should i do? the magras component is cardinal :3